# Looking for a way to shrink the size of MP3 files

Tags: internal-storage, mp3

I have a lot of MP3 files on my phone and I would like to re-size them to save space. (Note: I do not want to trim the audio file.)  I know I may lose some quality, but it is fine.
What is the best way to do this?  Perhaps an app? (Free is preferred)

Comment: I've re-worded the question for clarity, and made it sound less like an app shopping request.

Comment: Is doing this on the phone itself a requirement?  There are a myriad of both paid and free applications for Windows/Mac/Linux that can easily manipulate audio files by down-sampling them or converting to other more efficient formats to save on storage space.

Comment: It is easier to me have that on the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For doing the conversion on device itself, I would suggest searching the Google Play Store for [audio conversion apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=audio%20convert&c=apps).  Several results look like viable candidates: [The File Converter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghostmobile.mediaconverter) and [Convert Audio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.convertaudio), for example.  The features to look for are downsampling, changing bitrate and frequency, conversion to more efficient formats like OGG, AIC or FLACC.  I recommend trying each app yourself on one or two MP3 files to see if you get the results you want.  Play Store's 15-minute refund policy should give you enough time to figure out if the app is worth the price.

With that said, I would highly recommend doing the conversion on your PC instead.  First, by copying your MP3s from the phone to the PC you are making a backup.  Just in case something goes wrong during the conversion process, you will not lose the original file from your handset.  Second, there are a lot more choices in terms of software on Windows/Mac/Linux for audio file manipulation (especially the free and open-source variety,) and may also be able to do this in batch (i.e. convert multiple files automatically.)